# Neo4j query performance with memory tuning

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph (User-[Likes]->Item) with millions nodes and billions nodes (roughly 50G in disk) built on a powerful machine with 256G RAM and 40 cores. Currently, I'm computing the allshortestpath() between two items.

To improve the cypher query performance, I set `dbms.pagecache.memory=100g` and  `wrapper.java.additional=-Xmx32g`, with the hope that the whole neo4j can be loaded into meomory. However, when I execute the shortestpath query, the CPU usage is 1625% while MEMORY usage is only 5.7%, and I didn't see performance improvements on the cypher query. Am I missing something in the setting? Or can I setup something to run the query faster? I have read the Performance Tuning guide in the developer manual but didn't find solution.

**EDIT1:**
The cypher query is to count the number of unique users that like both two items. The full pattern would be (Brand)-[:Has]->(Item)<-[:LIKES]-(User)-[:LIKES]->(Item)<-[:HAS]-(Brand)

```
profile 
MATCH p = allShortestPaths((p1:Brand {FID:'001'})-[*..4]-(p2:Brand {FID:'002'})) 
with [r in RELS(p)|type(r)] as relationshipPath, 
[n in nodes(p)|id(n)][2] as user, p1, p2  
return p1.FID, p2.FID, count(distinct user);
```

**EDIT2:**
Below is a sampler query plan. It now seems that I'm not using shortestsPath efficiently (380,556,69 db hits). I use shortestsPath to get the common user node between start/end nodes, and then use count(distinct) to get the unique user. Is it possible to tell cypher to eliminate paths which contain the node that have been visited before?

[image]

Comment: Can you add the Cypher query, please? And the query plan (add `PROFILE` to the beginning of the query)?

Comment: Hey William, Please see the update. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: If you upgrade to 3.0 you could use some of the APOC procedure to paralellize the query and use all your cores.

Comment: My version is 2.3.4. I will upgrade to 3.0 and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run this instead:

```
MATCH (p1:Brand {FID:'001'}),(p2:Brand {FID:'002'})
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE (p1)-[:Has]->()<-[:LIKES]-(u) AND 
      (p2)-[:Has]->()<-[:LIKES]-(u)
RETURN p1,p2,count(u);
```

This starts at the user and checks against both brands, the explain plan looks much better

```
+----------------------+----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| Operator             | Estimated Rows | Variables                                | Other                     |
+----------------------+----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| +ProduceResults      |              0 | count(u), p1, p2                         | p1, p2, count(u)          |
| |                    +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation    |              0 | count(u) -- p1, p2                       | p1, p2                    |
| |                    +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| +SemiApply           |              0 | p2 -- p1, u                              |                           |
| |\                   +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | +Expand(Into)      |              0 | anon[78] -- anon[87], anon[89], p1, u    | (p1)-[:Has]->()           |
| | |                  +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)       |              0 | anon[87], anon[89] -- p1, u              | (u)-[:LIKES]->()          |
| | |                  +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | +Argument          |              1 | p1, u                                    |                           |
| |                    +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| +SemiApply           |              0 | p1 -- p2, u                              |                           |
| |\                   +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | +Expand(Into)      |              0 | anon[119] -- anon[128], anon[130], p2, u | (p2)-[:Has]->()           |
| | |                  +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | +Expand(All)       |              0 | anon[128], anon[130] -- p2, u            | (u)-[:LIKES]->()          |
| | |                  +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | +Argument          |              1 | p2, u                                    |                           |
| |                    +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| +CartesianProduct    |              0 | u -- p1, p2                              |                           |
| |\                   +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | +CartesianProduct  |              0 | p2 -- p1                                 |                           |
| | |\                 +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | | +Filter          |              0 | p1                                       | p1.FID == {  AUTOSTRING0} |
| | | |                +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | | +NodeByLabelScan |              0 | p1                                       | :Brand                    |
| | |                  +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | +Filter            |              0 | p2                                       | p2.FID == {  AUTOSTRING1} |
| | |                  +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| | +NodeByLabelScan   |              0 | p2                                       | :Brand                    |
| |                    +----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan     |              0 | u                                        | :User                     |
+----------------------+----------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Michael, are you suggesting not to use allshortestsPath()? However, due to huge size of user nodes (~200 millions), the above query is even slower...